# Speeding-up las files processing in a chunk with buffer

Tags: lidar, lidr

My aim is to do tree segmentation from lidar data. I have 15 las files and I want to merge them before segmentation. I realized that using chunk with buffer helps to get a proper segmentation.

When I use segmentation for each las tile, 1 meter gaps are occurring between the tiles. Therefore, I believe that before running segmentation codes, it is better to use catalog and chunk buffer. The problem is that my 2 laptops could not finish segmentation. It seems that it takes too much time and my laptops are not so powerful.

Is there anyway to merge las tiles and run the segmentation without any gap?

Here are the codes that I used in R:

```r
ctg = readLAScatalog("path/to/catalog")
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 0 
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 500 
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "path/to/new/catalog/Forest_{ID}"
newctg = catalog_retile(ctg)
las <- readLAS(newctg, filter="-keep_class 2 5")
dtm <- grid_terrain(las, algorithm = knnidw(k = 8, p = 2))
las_normalized <- lasnormalize(las, dtm)
lasfilternoise = function(las, sensitivity)
{
  p95 <- grid_metrics(las, ~quantile(Z, probs = 0.95), 10)
  las <- lasmergespatial(las, p95, "p95")
  las <- lasfilter(las, Z < p95*sensitivity)
  las$p95 <- NULL
  return(las)
}
las_denoised <- lasfilternoise(las_normalized, sensitivity = 1.2)
chm <- grid_canopy(las_denoised, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(3,1.5), subcircle = 0.2))
ker <- matrix(1,5,5)
chm_s <- focal(chm, w = ker, fun = median)
algo <- watershed(chm_s, th = 4)
las_watershed  <- lastrees(las_denoised, algo)
trees <- lasfilter(las_watershed, !is.na(treeID))
hulls  <- tree_hulls(trees, type = "concave", concavity = 2, func = .stdmetrics)
```

Comment: Please explain why you think that merging 15 files into a super massive one will speed up the segmentation. Also please show your code.

Comment: I used the codes in 16th page of lidR pdf documentation and I need to use a catalog with chunks. Otherwise, after tree segmentation, 1 meter gap occur between each tile which I can not digitize manually.

Comment: I used the retile and assume catalog as a single las file. And I tried to do a tree segmentation. I will hire a pc to do this analysis but first I need to understand whether there is a way to speed up segmentation

Comment: my pc could not complete the analysis. If I do not use catalog with a chunk, 1 meters gap occur between las tiles. I tried to ask this for several times here.

Comment: I edited my question again. Sorry! but I could not find a way to make a space between the codes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load you 15 files into a single point cloud you did it well.

```r
las <- readLAS(newctg, filter="-keep_class 2 5")
```

However this is a **very bad** idea. It is almost impossible to work like this you don't have enough memory. This is why you can't complete the process. And this is why `lidR` has an [engine to process a collection of file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAScatalog-class.html).

First you want to create a DTM

```r
ctg = readLAScatalog("path/to/catalog/")
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-keep_class 2 5"
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 50 
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 0 
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "path/to/DTM/DTM_{ORIGINALFILENAME}"
dtm <- grid_terrain(las, algorithm = knnidw(k = 8, p = 2))
```

Then normalize with a DTM (I assumed not with `knnidw` otherwise I don't see the interest of making a DTM).

```r
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-keep_class 2 5"
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 50 
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 0 
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "path/to/newcatalog/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_normalized"
ctg_norm <- lasnormalize(las, dtm)
```

Then filter noise (with a function that is not made for that as mentioned in the vignette where you took this code)

```r
lasfilternoise = function(chunk, sensitivity)
{
  las <- readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  p95 <- grid_metrics(las, ~quantile(Z, probs = 0.95), 10)
  las <- lasmergespatial(las, p95, "p95")
  las <- lasfilter(las, Z < p95*sensitivity)
  las$p95 <- NULL
  las <- lasfilter(las, buffer == 0L)
  return(las)
}

opt_filter(ctg_norm) <- "-keep_class 2 5"
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg_norm) <- 20 
opt_chunk_size(ctg_norm) <- 0 
opt_output_files(ctg_norm) <- "path/to/newcatalogdenoised/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_normalized_denoised"
ctg_norm_denoised <- catalog_apply(ctg_norm, lasfilternoise, sensitivity = 1.2)
```

Then the canopy

```r
opt_filter(ctg_norm_denoised) <- "-keep_class 2 5"
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg_norm_denoised) <- 0 
opt_chunk_size(ctg_norm_denoised) <- 0 
opt_output_files(ctg_norm_denoised) <- "path/to/CHM/CHM_{ORIGINALFILENAME}"
chm <- grid_canopy(ctg_norm_denoised, 0.5, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(3,1.5), subcircle = 0.2))
```

The engine loads one tile at a time, takes care of loading a buffer and so on... I'm not demonstrating the tree segmentation here because it is more complex and the question turned to be *How to use the `LAScatalog`*. Try it yourself and if you get struggled please ask a new question with a reproducible example of what you tried. Good luck.

Side note: Computing concave hull on 15 tiles is extremely heavy for all computers. See https://github.com/Jean-Romain/RcppConcaveman to get a chance to compute it.

Comment: Thanks. When it runs dtm <- grid_terrain(las, algorithm = knnidw(k = 8, p = 2)), processing gets stuck at 29% and does not continue. That was the reason I used las <- readLAS(newctg, filter="-keep_class 2 5") although I know it is a stupid idea. And that was the reason why I asked about speeding up

Comment: Processing [=========================================>--------------------------------------------------]  29% (4/14) eta: 23m

Comment: It is impossible to answer without seeing the data Try with a triangulation instead.

Comment: May I use lasvoxelize to merge my las tiles?

Comment: What `lasvoxelize` has to do with file merging? Anyway, don't merge your file. If you have a never ending dtm computation it is maybe a bug. Maybe you should report that with a fully reproducible example